# Is this cloth jacket surrounding my electrical asbestos?

Tags: electrical, insulation, wire, socket

Checked to see what was going on behind the electrical socket, and discovered this fibrous wire insulation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I think who ever installed this 3 prong outlet in the first place did so illegally because the ground pin is not connected to anything, nor was the outlet labeled.

Edit: Another 2 images from a grounded socket:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "probably" or "almost certainly" regarding is it asbestos. What label did you expect to see on the outlet? Do you mean a UL rating? If the wire is only 2 conductor then it at least points to a high liklihood that it is not grounded as there may not even be a ground. That is a metal box, so if it was run via conduit then "it probably is grounded" by means of the chassis, but you are right it should be wired with a ground, to the box if that is the case. I'd recommend calling a contractor because you sincerely do not want to risk breathing the dust.

Comment: That does not look like asbestos fibres to me - or at least like the asbestos fibres I have seen in the past... But get someone to check as guessing from images on the net is not perfect.

Comment: Yea, I should have really prefaced it with 'treat it as ...'. Even with these high quality photos the potential is still there. I was not aiming to say "yes it is"

Comment: @noybman did not pick on your comment - we were writing in parallel - only saw yours once I posted mine.

Comment: I certainly breathed it already by accident /: Some threads state that a ungrounded 3 prong outlet needs to be labeled no equipment ground when the ground isnt connected to anything.

Comment: See the receptacle yoke, where the screws go through it?  See the metal box it's screwing into?  Does the yoke have hard, metal-on-metal contact with the metal box, or is it floating proud of the box because of the drywall ears?  If the latter, are there metal spacers the screw is going through?

Comment: @Harper here’s the scoop. Given your comment I gave it another look. Actually the receptacle was just floating on air, so I tried screwing it in as far as it could go because yes the dry wall actually does prevent it from going all the way, and there were no spacers. The tester still read the outlet as ungrounded. But I couldn't screw it in all the way to be sure either.

Comment: I added another 2 images of the behind of a grounded socket. To my surprise it seems that socket also lacks a ground wire which means the previous socket would probably be grounded as well if not for the dry wall. https://imgur.com/a/CfsyedQ What do you think? Don’t mind the critter there having a blast!

Comment: You did what!!!??  *Drywall ears are **supposed to** hold it proud of the box and even with the wall*.  I just meant that if it *was* flush or had spacers, that's a valid grounding path and that explains the lack of ground.  And in the past, Code allowed grounding via the screws themselves, so that would be legal; that's not allowed *today* for *receptacles* but is still allowed for switches.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure I understand if the drywall ears are part of the box or the receptacle. Here is an image of the mounting situation: https://imgur.com/DEddHse I live in Ontario, Canada. The receptacle hangs loose on the screw because the drywall prevents it from being screwed into the box. There are no spacers between the box and receptacle. Edit: Okay I get it, the drywall ears are on the receptacle and need to be there to align it. The handy man who installed this receptacle should've used spacers. Is this correct?

Comment: I see spacers are made of plastic. So they must push the receptacle to the screw tip where it can make good contact with it and thus the mounting box as the screw is screwed in there.